Nextjs tRPC Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.createContext) is not a function
i am getting error of createContext i checkout for every possible solution don't know why this error is coming.
describing more about it:
getting createContext not a function error
checked many repo with example at step are same and dependencies are proper
trpc.ts
import { initTRPC, TRPCError } from "@trpc/server";

const t = initTRPC.context().create();

export const router = t.router;
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;

client.ts
import { createTRPCReact } from "@trpc/react-query";
import type { AppRouter } from ".";

export const trpc = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>({});

index.ts
import {  publicProcedure, router } from "./trpc";
import { z } from "zod";

export const appRouter = router({
  test: publicProcedure.query(() => {
    return "test";
  }),
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;

provider.tsx
"use client";

import { PropsWithChildren, useState } from "react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { trpc } from "@/trpc/client";
import { httpBatchLink } from "@trpc/client";

const Providers = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient());

  const [trpcClient] = useState(() =>
    trpc.createClient({
      links: [
        httpBatchLink({
          url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/trpc`,
          fetch(url, options) {
            return fetch(url, {
              ...options,
              credentials: "include",
            });
          },
        }),
      ],
    })
  );

  return (
    <trpc.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
    </trpc.Provider>
  );
};

export default Providers;

Getting this error:

Dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.36.1",
    "@trpc/client": "^10.45.2",
    "@trpc/next": "^10.45.2",
    "@trpc/react-query": "^10.45.2",
    "@trpc/server": "^10.45.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.399.0",
    "next": "^14.2.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },

i need the reason why is it coming or some guide to fix the issue

Hello updating this question after 10 minutes because I got the solution when querying data with trpc.test.useQuery() that page should be at client side not server side
